# How to define context in for AWS CDK python pytests

Tags: python, pytest, aws-cdk

### Goal

To run AWS CDK Python unit tests that validate configuration properties

### Problem

While pytest correctly creates the cdk.App object, it fails to read `cdk.json` for some reason.

### Conditions

- Tested tests/cdk.json
- Tested tests/unit/cdk.json
- Tested values in ./cdk.json

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Workaround

Force context within pytest file ([ref](https://github.com/aws/aws-cdk/issues/4359#issuecomment-537944331))

eg:

```
TEST_VALUE = "10.1.0.0/20"

TEST_CONTEXT = {
    "cidr": TEST_VALUE,
  }

def test_config():
    app = cdk.App(context=TEST_CONTEXT)
    # app = cdk.App()  # This fails to get values from cdk.json
    stack = MyStack(app, "mycdk")
    template = assertions.Template.from_stack(stack)

    # Verify cdk.json values
    template.has_resource_properties("AWS::EC2::VPC", {
        "CidrBlock": TEST_CIDR
    })
```